# How do I make the scrollbar on a div only visible when the pointer is on the div?

Tags: html, css

I have this div:

```
<div style='overflow:auto; width:50px;height:50px;'>here is some text</div>
```

The scrollbars is visible because text is to long. But there are 2 behaviors on my mac:

- os 10.15: the scrollbar is always visible
- os <10.15: the scrollbar
  becomes visible only when the pointer comes on the div and disseapear
  when the pointer leave the div, which make the screen more pleasant
  to watch.

I got the same difference on every browser (safari, firefox, chrome, opera).
Does anybody know a solution to make the scroolbar visible only when the pointer is on the div even on 10.15 ?

Edit: the answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631799/make-scrollbars-only-visible-when-a-div-is-hovered-over)

Comment: please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631799/make-scrollbars-only-visible-when-a-div-is-hovered-over)
hope it helps.

Comment: Many thanks !  I have searched for it but did not found !