# WebKit not painting/repainting dynamic images in mobile Safari (unless an alert is shown or device orientation changed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, webkit

Mobile Safari is not rendering images on our HTML5 website. These images are added dynamically via JavaScript.

We have tried the suggestions from these places, but none work for us:

- [How can I force WebKit to redraw/repaint to propagate style changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes)
- [Webkit box-shadow gitches on top of the other elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932697/webkit-box-shadow-gitches-on-top-of-the-other-elements/8948220#8948220)
- http://mrdarcymurphy.tumblr.com/post/5574489334/force-mobile-safari-to-repaint-redraw

The only things that cause the images to get rendered are if we either ask the user to turn the device orientation to landscape, or if we show a JavaScript alert. Once the user dismisses the alert modal, the images get rendered.

Steps:

1) Visit [Tekiki.com](http://www.tekiki.com) on your iPhone. Make sure Wi-Fi is disabled (happens less consistently with Wi-Fi).

2) Tap on one of the apps. Images (app screenshots) on the bottom of the page will only appear if you turn the device sideways.

What else can we do to force WebKit to repaint/paint these images?