# jQuery style not being applied in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, macos, safari

I have an absolutely positioned element that I move with the help of jQuery using the CSS propertly 'left'.

```
$("#element").css('left', '103px');
```

In Firefox this works as expected. However in Safari I can see the style appearing in the Web Inspector under element.style, but the style isn't updated. If I disable (and re-enable) any matched CSS-rules (even those not applied directly to my div) the style being applied with jQuery is rendered.

I'm running Safari 5.0.6 on an old PowerMac, with jQuery 1.7.2.

Comment: How about adding a class with left:103px; to you CSS and doing $('emelent').addClass('left_class'); ? Will that make a differance?

Comment: If it is in the CSS it works, but I want to be able to move the element around with jQuery, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I've traced the problem to a parent element to this one which is absolutely positioned. If I set it to relative positioning it will render the jQuery applied style.

Comment: Can you post a working web page demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 13):

I faced this problem once and i end up using addClass and removeClass on elements parent container.

try this

```
$("#element").css('left', '103px').parent().addClass("dummyClass").removeClass("dummyClass");
```

if that doesn't work follwoing will work for sure.

```
$("#element").css('left', '103px');
$("body").addClass("dummyClass").removeClass("dummyClass");
```

the problem is sometime safari doesn't redraw the page when we change CSS so we need to force redrawing

Comment: dude, you are a life saver!
$("body").addClass("dummyClass").removeClass("dummyClass"); works

Comment: glad it helped you.  yes some time immediate parent is not causing problem so you need to move level up. usually body solves the problem. the only case where i see adding class on body doesn't work is when you have element inside td and in that case you need add/remove class or sometime add/remove attribute align on td.

Answer (score 0):

!important should do the trick

```
$("#element").css('left', '103px !important');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem implementing a video progress bar. The element I wanted to position let was inside a DIV with 'display:table-caption;' After reading @gaurang171 comment on td elements, I ended up having to remove that element from the div table and setting 'display:block;' and the element position updated without the need for the dummyClass. A div with display:block inside the table-caption did not work, it had to be outside of the table altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Safari seems to have problem with repainting elements. Fortunately we can force repaint by adding `transform: translateZ(0);` to css class. This seems to be fixed on BigSur, but happens on Safari Catalina.