# CSS/Javascript - button and link not detecting hover or click? Even with z index highest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Havaing an odd problem that I've concluded does not have to do with z index - I first had this as an a href and now have a button but with both had the same problem of mouse hover and mouse click NOT being detected. At all.

I echo html here:

```
<?php

//---------------------------------------------------------------------   

echo '<div class="wrapper">';
echo '<h1 class = "abtHeader"></h1>';

echo '<div id = "paragraph"> <br></div>';
echo '<div id = "paragraph2">  </div>';

echo '<button type="submit" class="register-button" name="Register">Register</button>';
//echo '<a class "register" href = "../"><div>Register</div></a>';

echo '<ul class="bg-bubbles">';
echo '<li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>';
echo '</ul>';

echo '</div>';

?>
```

Then my CSS where I try to detect hover (no change in background color made):

```
.register-button {

    z-index: 5;
    padding-top: 100px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #53e3a6;
height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
}
.register-button:hover {
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
}
```

Then my javascript func which is not executedL

```
//Register 
    $(".register-button").on('click', function(e){
        console.log("go to register");

        header('Location: ../register');

    });
```

I've tried moving the z index up however this makes no difference. Why isn't mouse hover/click detected on my button?

Comment: Working fine in my environment..

Comment: Can you show us some working code where we can see the issue and debug it?

Comment: On what browser is this experienced ? Would it be on safari-mobile? If so, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504446/my-jquery-toggleclass-function-is-creating-a-hyperlink-effect-on-touchscreen-dev/37515539#37515539)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that code.  In fact, if you load it into a snippet it works fine.  Only problems I can see:

- In your commented out `<a class "register" href = "../"><div>Register</div></a>` you are missing `=` after `class`.  But that's irrelevant.
- `header('Location: ../register');` is php, not javascript.  As Dmitry mentioned above, for that to work you'd need something like `window.location.href = "../register";`

Please post your actual code or the html that's rendered, and maybe we can help spot the problem.

See snippet below, CSS works fine and styles are applied:

```js
//Register 
$(".register-button").on('click', function(e) {
  $('.console').html('.register-button clicked');

});
```

```css
.register-button {
  z-index: 5;
  padding-top: 100px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #53e3a6;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}
.register-button:hover {
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
}
.console {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="abtHeader"></h1>
  <div id="paragraph">
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id="paragraph2">T</div>
  <button type="submit" class="register-button" name="Register">Register</button>
  <div class="console"></div>
  <div>Register</div>

  <ul class="bg-bubbles">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a CSS hover-effect on button from your code. About js: try to change `header('Location: ../register');` to `window.location.href = "../register";`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mitwebulus/xn4b3mru/)

Comment: Good correction on code... But still does'nt answers the main problem of the `hover` effect. Well, `click` was certainly bugging... Ok. ;) Uncomplete answer.

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette, Except this error, everything works correctly. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mitwebulus/xn4b3mru/

Answer (score 1):

you create a dynamic button then you need to create function and call that function on click like

Buttuon

```
<button type="submit" class="register-button" name="Register" onclick="bClick()" onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mOut(this)">Register</button>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javaScript">

function bClick(){
    console.log("go to register");
    header('Location: ../register');
}

function mOver(obj) {
    this.style.backgroundColor='#f5f7f9';return true
}

function mOut(obj) {
    this.style.backgroundColor='#fff';return true
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that because you place you js code before you html? Then when the jquery find the dom,it's not rendered,so jquery can't bind the listener on that.

```
see code in the jsfiddle below
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/965q77b2/)

or you can just change you js code like this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() { 
        $(".register-button").on('click', 
            function(e){ console.log("go to register");
            header('Location: ../register'); 
        }); 
    }
);
```