# jquery datepicker year/month change for fullcalendar not triggering in iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, fullcalendar

I am using jquery datepicker to trigger year/month change for fullcalendar, it just works fine for all browsers, all PC screens and all android phones but its not working in iphones.

I have used jquery datepicker to trigger fullcalendar year/month change, here is my code

```
$("#myhcalendar").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOn: 'both',
            onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, objDatePicker) {

                var monthnew=("0" + (month + 1)).slice(-2);
                console.log(monthnew+'-'+'10'+'-'+year);
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',  monthnew-1+''+'-'+'10'+'-'+year);
                //on change of date remove event-container 
                $('.fc-content-skeleton>table tbody td').removeClass('fc-event-container');
            }
        })
```

myhcalendar is jquery datepicker id, and #calendar is id for fullcalendar. this works perfect in all devices except in iphone. Any suggestions?

**update: just now I saw by adding alert() before  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',  monthnew-1+''+'-'+'10'+'-'+year); works but adding alert after this line does not working in iphone, there must be problem with gotodate**
Please comment if any other code is required to view. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like this problem is getting common. :) See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504446/my-jquery-toggleclass-function-is-creating-a-hyperlink-effect-on-touchscreen-dev/37515539#37515539) (this week) on what *may be* your problem related to `.addClass()` - `.removeClass()`

Comment: no thats not what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use (/) instead of hyphen (-)

as below

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',  monthnew-1+''+'/'+'10'+'/'+year);
```

Comment: did u try my answer?, what is value of monthnew?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add the following to prevent selection?

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Comment: for which class I need to add above css?

Comment: the datepicker input, #myhcalendar must be the id I think.