# Element style modified with jquery .css is not being refreshed on Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, select, width

I am updating the width of a select element, using .css, when occurs an onchange event.
In HTML:

```
<select name="city_search" id="city_search" onchange='resetDropDown("#state_search");'>
<select name="state_search" id="state_search" onchange='resetDropDown("#city_search");'>
```

In JS

```
function resetDropDown(elementObj)
{
    var selectBoxWidth = $(elementObj).attr('id') == 'college_search' ? 143 : 113;
    $(elementObj).css({width:selectBoxWidth});
}
```

For some reason, the attribute width is correctly changed, but chrome does not show the changes until the element is inspected or page is refreshed.
Is there a way to force chrome to show the changes applied on the element style?

Thanks in advance.
Elizabeth

Comment: seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/cZf3A/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem can be solved by force the webkit to redraw/repaint the style changes. You can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3485654/567101

Comment: Thanks a lot. Forcing the webkit to redraw element worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution worked for me. 
Try to change `$(document).ready` to `$(window).load`

The problem may be on getting the document ready. If function runs once windows loads then it may work.

Answer (score 0):

OnChange event fires only when object changes AND loose focus. Your could use some workaround like using keyup event for text inputs or click event for checkboxes. Depending on a context of select change you may need to manually trigger change event.
I suggest onclick instead of onchange should work for you if your select element changes when user chooses different option.