# Float and Inline-block doesn't work sometimes in webkit

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I detect a problem that affects divs positioned in columns with `float` and with `display: inline-block`. Let me show two examples:
[image]

In the first case (left) the name "Altair" and the button "Log-Out" are positioned with display inline-block. The desired result is shown in the first row, what happens ALWAYS when I modify the content of the div dynamically with JQuery is shown in the second row. When I write all the html the first time all is correct.

In the other case (right) the number "21" is positioned with float: left and then pushes the month and the year. In this case the content is always inserted with JQuery and the problem shown in the second row only appears SOMETIMES, when I refresh the page. 1 of 5 times, more or less.

As you can see, Chrome console says that the div has 0px of width, and probably this is what triggers the problem. I can reproduce the first case (left) in Safari, but not the ohter (right). I can't reproduce the errors in Firefox and Opera, then I suppose that is something related with Webkit.

Do you know what is happening and can I solve this? Thank you for your attention.

HTML and CSS first case:

```
<div id="login-widget" class="widget">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="button in">
        <div class="value">Log - Out
        </div><div class="decorator"></div>
    </div>
</div>

#login-widget .name {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
#login-widget .button {
    border: solid 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML and CSS for the other case:

```
<div class="date">
    <div class="day"></div>
    <div class="month"></div>
    <div class="year"></div>
</div>

#agenda-widget .date {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#agenda-widget .day {
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: #DB443F;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#agenda-widget .month {
    padding-top: 12px;
}
#agenda-widget .year {
    /*nothing*/
}
```

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Comment: Post your html and css markup please

Comment: I smell `position:absolute` somewhere

Comment: I edited the entry with the code. I doesn't posted them before because I thank all is very normal...

There is no `position:absolute` or `position:relative` in all the internal code of this widgets. But every widget container is `position:relative`.

Comment: By the way, inherit properties are purelly stetical (font, lineHeight, color...).

Comment: The font is from google web fonts (Montserrat). I used Arial instead and the problem persists. Then is not an issue related with the custom font.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is a Webkit bug. Fortunelly, it can be solved by forcing webkit to repaint the element. As pointed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes) a trick to do this is with this simple javascript code:

```
sel.style.display='none';
sel.offsetHeight; // no need to store this anywhere, the reference is enough
sel.style.display='block';
```

If someone find a better solution I would mark it as the correct answer, but at the moment this works and could help other people with the same problem.