# Inline-block works sometimes

Tags: css

Hey guys having a nightmare at the moment I'm unsure what is causing this bizarre problem.

Basically sometimes the elements I have set as inline-block's work and then when I refresh the browser they decide they no longer want to be inline.

Here is my HTML:

```
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-8">
        <div class="listing-container">
          <h3 class="model-listing-title clearfix">2011 (11) Mercedes-Benz C Class C250 CDI BlueEFFICIENCY Sport 4dr Auto</h3>
          <h3 class="price-listing clearfix">£17,998</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="listing-container-spec">
          <img src="media/img/mercedes-test.jpg" alt="mercedes-benz"/>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.listing-container {
    background-color:#dddddd;
    padding:0;
    border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #9e9e9e;
    padding:1px 10px;
    overflow:auto;
}

.listing-container-spec {
    background-color:#153066;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

.listing-container-spec img {
    max-width:60%;

}

.model-listing-title {
    font: 600 1.5em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-top:0.1em;
    display:inline-block;
    width:75%;
}



.price-listing {
    font: 700 2em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-top:0.1em;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    margin-top:0.1em;
}
```

This is what it should look like:

[image: Expected Behavior]

This is after a few refreshes:

[image: Erratic Behavior]

I am using bootstrap just so you know, however if I put that code into JSFiddle it works fine however on my live site it changes it position on nearly every refresh.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Here is the live example: http://dealerbyte.co.uk/used-cars.php

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the two behaviors?

Comment: Yes I will do now, give me 3 minutes.

Comment: This is what it should look like:

http://content.screencast.com/users/nickmadd/folders/Jing/media/c0b9e78e-e3ba-43b6-9423-42798c8b8c74/2014-08-22_1420.png

This is after a few refreshes:

http://content.screencast.com/users/nickmadd/folders/Jing/media/cf98e21e-5dac-4b38-b484-b956df5158dd/2014-08-22_1421.png

Comment: I already had this problem... I can't remember why... I was using google chrome under ubuntu. I assumed this was a browser bug and closed my eyes on it since I didn't have this issue under other browsers and OS. It might also be because of an extension (ad block or something). The problem disappeared immediatly after pressing `F12`

Comment: This definitely looks like a browser issue. The issue appears if the page loads from the wire instead of cache. If you hide and show the `.price-listing` it appears at the correct location.

Comment: Yeah, it [sounds like a bug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13490643/645956). I'd probably get around it by using absolute positioning for that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did in the Chrome dev tools that seemed to fix the problem.

1. Remove `display: inline-block;` from `.model-listing-title` and `.price-listing`
2. Add `float: left;` to `.model-listing-title`