# CSS 100% height (while maintaining aspect ratio) trick triggers circular WebKit redraw bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I'm using this amazingly awesome CSS technique to force `<li>` to be as tall as their parent `<ol>`/`<ul>` while maintaining an aspect ratio of my choosing.

The idea is to craft a transparent GIF or PNG that features your target aspect ratio, then to use that image to stretch the `<li>` *proportionally*.

HTML:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <img src="1x1.gif" height="1" width="1">
    <div class="content">
      …
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol  { height: 50%; } /* half the height of the viewport, let's say */
li  { height: 100%; position: relative; display: inline-block; }
img { height: 100%; width: auto; }
.content { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
```

Sweet. Problem is, if you resize the `<ol>` by resizing the viewport, WebKit won't bother to recalculate the size of the `<img>`, and your aspect ratio is shot. If, however, you right click on the `<div class="content">` and choose “Inspect Element”, it snaps to size! So too when you enact [this heinous redraw hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3485654/802047):

```
var image = $('img').get(0);
var oldDisplay = image.style.display;

image.style.display = 'none';
image.offsetHeight; // Secret sauce
image.style.display = oldDisplay;
```

Really, I'm trying to size an `<img>` based on the size of an `<li>` whose size is based on that of the `<img>`. I suspect that there's an optimization in WebKit that punts on this kind of circular reference. What to do?

Here's a JSFiddle where you can experience the bug for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/steveluscher/H5Mkm/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably far from an answer- but I just used the same technique of a hidden image to make the surrounding div stretch & keep aspect ratio. Worked well for me. Maybe you can ignore the js and just see how the CSS/HTML are working in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/H2G7z/5/

```
 .
```

Comment: Ah yes. People with width-related problems have it easy. Mine is a height-related problem, ie. a world of hurt.