# Text on the label Not sliding with when clicked

Tags: css

I have an accordion slider. I have a problem with the slider label text, which is not sliding when clicked. [Here is the URL to my site.](http://pep-perspectives.com/734-2/)

CSS for the text:

```
.accordion label h7{ 
position: absolute;
cursor:pointer; 
display: block;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* fixes chrome bug */
-webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg); 
-webkit-transform-origin: right top; 
-moz-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform-origin: right top; 
-o-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg); 
-o-transform-origin: right top; 
transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg); 
transform-origin: right top;
}
```

What am I missing?  Is their a way to make the slider auto slider with some seconds lag?

Comment: I'm not getting the problem. For me the site looks fine. Could you maybe create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that is only showing the isolated problem? Also, what browsers does the problem occur in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.accordion label h7` is set to `position:absolute`. If you remove that you'll notice the text begins to slide.

A fix I found for the resulting bunched text is to set a width to `.accordion label h7`.

```
.accordion label h7 {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: But after removing this text messed up. what about that?

Comment: Thanks is their a way to make the slider auto rotate? in css3

Comment: @karthikpatruni: You may want to ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

The text is sliding, but it is not getting updated. As soon as some CSS properties change, the text jumps to the right position. So maybe try changing a CSS property before you start to animate the text and remove it again after your animation is complete (something like border-color which no one will ever see). ([Relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes))