# Body background CSS gradient isn't redrawn when JS changes page height

Tags: javascript, css, gradient

I'm using a 100% vertical CSS gradient as the background of the body element, as follows:

```
body {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,101,189,0.5) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,101,189,0.5) 0px,rgba(255,255,255,1) 600px);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,101,189,0.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,101,189,0.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,101,189,0.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    min-height: 100%;}
```

However, odd things happen when JS (in my case, bootstrap.js) dynamically changes the height of the page - for example, when the user opens collapsed sections of content but in other scenarios as well. The body background gradient isn't redrawn properly and appears "corrupted". See this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OYaN.jpg

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: FYI, I've tinkered with adding 100% height and min-height properties to the body and html elements - no help.

Answer (score 3):

There is a discussion about forcing the Webkit browser to reapply CSS styles: [How can I force WebKit to redraw/repaint to propagate style changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes)

The solution that worked for me was adding and removing empty `<style>` element after changing the page height:

```
$('<style></style>').appendTo($(document.body)).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to fix your problem.  But I've had this problem many times on various places I've used gradients (I primarily use Chrome).  I think it's more so up to the browser and how it implements the gradient.  It seems like it has a hard time re-painting it as needed.  You could possibly put your gradients in a class such as .gradient and then remove and add the class when you are done with your transition (there would be a slight visible flash going from the fragmented version to a new version).  This might force the browser to redraw the gradient, but I haven't tested it.  It's not perfect but it's all I got.