# Display block/none on absolute/relative elements on Mac browsers like safari/chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not sure if I titled my question properly but my description about the question with a demo link should give you a brief about the problem I'm facing.

I've a set of select elements which I'm customising writing some jquery script. To a greater extent I'm able to get the look of the elements customised.

I've some issue with the behaviour like when I click on the dropdown down, the options appear. I'm expecting to close this list of options when i select one of these options. But I see a strange behaviour. The option list closes but the view stays.

Please find the code I'm using to hide the option list.

```
$(document).delegate('.custom-dropdown .arrow, .custom-dropdown .text','click',function(e){
$(this).parents('.row').addClass('is-overflow-visible');
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/JSdPL/11/)

Please do ask me questions if I'm not able to explain properly.

Appreciate any help. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a show/hide of the parent element will fix it. Or this problem doesn't appear when you switch tabs after clicking on the select item.

I have edited the jsFiddle link you posted with the solution, you may try it.

```
var $el = $('.is-overflow-visible').removeClass('is-overflow-visible').parent().hide();
setTimeout(function () { $el.show() })
```

Refer: [How can I force WebKit to redraw/repaint to propagate style changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Let me have a look at the same.