# Centering in the unknown

Tags: html, css, centering

I would like to center and clamp the dimensions of a child div inside its parent.

```
<style type='text/css'>
  .parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .child {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <img src='dog.jpg' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here are the constraints:

- The parent div is set to occupy the entire screen (of unknown size), so `width:100%` and `height:100%`.
- The width and height of the child div are unknown. In one use case, the child div contains an image. In another, it contains a video.
- The width and height of the child div must be constrained to the size of the parent, so `max-width: 100%` and `max-height: 100%`.
- The child div must be vertically and horizontally centered inside the parent.
- Ideally, this should work without javascript.
- IE can be left unsupported :)

I've tried all the techniques listed in this excellent article, ['Absolute Centering in CSS'](http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt#Comparison-Table) , and none of them pan out. Here's why:

- **Absolute centering**: In order for this technique to work with a child of unknown size, you must set `display:table` on the child. You can then constrain the max-width of the child's contents, but not the max-height, because by CSS 2.1 rules, tables render to fit their contents.
- **Negative margins**: Doesn't allow for variable height.
- **Transforms**: Undesirable because it can result in blurry rendering.
- **Table-cell**: Fails for the same reason that absolute centering fails, i.e. table rendering.
- **Inline-block**: Doesn't work in the important case where the child is 100% width.
- **Flexbox**: Works well until a window resize occurs, at which point you have to force a Webkit redraw to propagate the centering changes. This [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes) does the job, but it's still a hack. I want to believe there's a more elegant solution to this.

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: I like the zen nature of this question's title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution here is to use `:before` pseudo element. Check out this article on centering the unknown, http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

**[SEE THE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sZFW7/1)**

```
body,html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
 }

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: #a0a0a0 solid 1px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
 }
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! It seems I was misled by the author of the [Absolute Centering](http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt) article. I still don't get what he's saying about the child div needing a width of 100% - 0.25em or less. Oh well, this answer will do :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` like so [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2YBft/1/). Though this will just center the **image** of the child div.

If you need to have a centered div around the image you could always add another div inside of the `child` div with the style `display: inline-block` [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2YBft/2/)