# Is DOM rendering GUARANTEED to block during a single (synchronous) function's execution?

Tags: javascript, dom, html-rendering

DOM blocking is something many people not familiar with JavaScript's strictly single-threaded synchronous execution model find out about the hard way, and it's usually just something we want to work around somehow (using timeouts, web-workers, etc). All well and good.

However, I would like to know if blocking of the actual user-visible rendering is something you can actually *rely* on. I'm 90% sure it is *de facto* the case in most browsers but I am hoping this isn't just a happily consistent accident. I can't seem to find any definitive statements from DOM specifications or even vendor documentation like MDM.

What worries me slightly is that while changes to the DOM are indeed not visible looking at the page, the internal DOM geometry (including CSS transforms and filters) *does* actually update during synchronous execution. For example:

```
console.log(element.getBoundingRect().width);
element.classList.add("scale-and-rotate");
console.log(element.getBoundingRect().width);
element.classList.remove("scale-and-rotate");
```

... will indeed report two different width values, though the page does not *appear* to flash. Synchronously waiting after the class is added (using a while loop) doesn't make the temporary changes visible either. Doing a Timeline trace in Chrome reveals that internally paint and re-paint is taking place just the same, which makes sense...

My concern is that, lacking a specific reason not, some browsers, like say, those dealing with underpowered mobile CPUs, may choose to actually reflect those internal calculations in the user-visible layout *during* that function's execution, and thus will result in an ugly "flash" during such temporary operations. So, more concretely, what I'm asking is: Do they have a specific reason not to?

(If you are wondering why I care about this at all, I sometimes need to measure calculated dimensions using `getBoundingRect` for elements in a certain state to plan out spacing or animations or other such things, without actually putting them in that state or animating them first...)

Comment: Updated values are updated to DOM instantly, but they are not _rendered_ before the script is finished, except: Looks like [window.scrollBy()](http://jsfiddle.net/6HXsP/) is updated during the execution in IEs. In the fiddle resize the "Result" window so small that you can scroll it, then click "Scroll" button.

Comment: @user2864740 how's that?

Comment: @Teemu - so what's your source for knowing that? I believe you of course, but I am specifically asking if this behaviour is something that *happens* to be true or if it's officially specced out somewhere and can be relied on. It certainly is worrying that there are exceptions :/

Comment: The source is me, yes, but you can visit the fiddle with any IE, and see smooth scrolling. Unfortenately I can't point you any official source explaining this behavior in IEs, but the fiddle itself proofs, that at least this is exceptional in IEs.

Comment: I guess what you are searching for is the documentation for layout engine behavior, not DOM behavior. Unfortunately each engine has its own internal way to do things, be it a cyclic update or an event based update (which can be very costly). There is no official doc for layout engines which is now the core of the browser war...

Comment: @rubyruy Visiting your fiddle with my version of IE (version 11) does not show smooth scrolling - it looks identical to Chrome. So this might only be true for older versions of IE.

Comment: @rubyruy have you found any authoritative source since then?

Comment: @brillout.com - Here are a few unofficial documents which explain when the page layout is up to date and methods to force a repaint: (1) [Paul Irish's comprehensive list](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a), (2) [an article by A. Skutin](http://frontendbabel.info/articles/webpage-rendering-101/), (3) the "classic" [offsetHeight call](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3485654/1009922). As I understand it, making a call to get an element position or size will force a repaint if necessary.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Is this behavior guaranteed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in Javascript related to concurrency that is anything but de facto.  JS simply does not define a concurrency model.  Everything is happy accident or years of consensus.

That said, if your function does not make any calls to weird things like XMLHttpRequest or "alert" or something like that, you can basically treat it as single-threaded with no interrupts.

Comment: Well, this seems to be our running theory, in the absence of evidence to the contrary. Probably as good as it gets.

Comment: AJAX is hardly the only source of race conditions! Example: `x.innerHTML = '<div id="herp">'; document.getElementById('herp');` may often return `null`.

Comment: Any source to confirm this?

Answer (score 7):

According to various sources, getting the position or size of a DOM element will trigger a reflow of the output if necessary, so that the returned values are correct. As a matter of fact, reading the `offsetHeight` of an element has become a way to force a reflow, as reported by [Alexander Skutin](http://frontendbabel.info/articles/webpage-rendering-101/) and [Daniel Norton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3485654/1009922).

[Paul Irish](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) gives a list of several actions that cause a reflow. Among them are these element box metrics methods and properties:

> - elem.offsetLeft, elem.offsetTop, elem.offsetWidth, elem.offsetHeight,
> - elem.offsetParent elem.clientLeft, elem.clientTop, elem.clientWidth,
> - elem.clientHeight elem.getClientRects(), elem.getBoundingClientRect()

[Stoyan Stefanov](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/) describes strategies used by browsers to optimize reflows (e.g. queueing DOM changes and performing them in batches), and adds the following remark:

> But sometimes the script may prevent the browser from optimizing the
>   reflows, and cause it to flush the queue and perform all batched
>   changes. This happens when you request style information, such as
>
> 1. offsetTop, offsetLeft, offsetWidth, offsetHeight
> 2. scrollTop/Left/Width/Height
> 3. clientTop/Left/Width/Height
> 4. getComputedStyle(), or currentStyle in IE
>
> All of these above are essentially requesting style information about
>   a node, and any time you do it, the browser has to give you the most
>   up-to-date value. In order to do so, it needs to apply all scheduled
>   changes, flush the queue, bite the bullet and do the reflow.

Comment: You are confusing repaint and reflow. Nothing can force a repaint.

Comment: @Kaiido - Thanks for pointing that out. I modified the answer.