# I'm having an issue with knockout's beforeRemove callback and CSS transitions

Tags: knockout.js

I am using the foreach binding along with the beforeRemove callback in order to animate the removal of my list items. It is working fine when I remove an item above the item I just previously removed, but when I attempt to remove an item below the item previously removed, the transition doesn't work correctly.

Here is a jsfiddle illustrating my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/tylerweeres/2szjxzs0/2/

HTML

```
<h3>Animations</h3>
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: people, beforeRemove: animateOut }">
    <div style="padding: 5px;" class="person">
        <span data-bind="text: name" style="display: inline-block; width: 200px;"></span>
        <button style="padding: 5px 15px;" data-bind="click: $parent.removePerson">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.person {
    font-family: georgia;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: 75px;
}

.person.remove {
    transform: translateX(2000px) rotateZ(540deg);
}
```

JS

```js
function vm () {
    "use strict";
    var me = this;

    me.people = ko.observableArray([
        { "name": "Irma Olsen" },
        { "name": "Winifred Cabrera" },
        // ...
        { "name": "Lucius Howard" },
        { "name": "Hedda Santana" }
    ]);

    me.removePerson = function (person) {
        me.people.remove(person);
    };

    me.animateOut = function animateOut(node, i, person) {
        // Make sure it's not a text node
        if (node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            node.classList.add("remove");
        }
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a weird one, but I think it has to do with crazy browser rendering logic stuff.  You need to force a redraw that isn't happening.  At one point we have:

```
<div class="person remove">
<div class="person">
```

Then we go to

```
<div class=person>
<div class=person>
```

The same div doesn't have the `remove` class anymore -- when we add the `remove` class, Knockout removes the data, but the browser doesn't know to update this div and so it doesn't perform the transition which means `transitionEnd` doesn't fire and the div doesn't get removed either.

So how do we force a redraw?  [Obviously by calling `node.offsetHeight`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes) (a valid expression).

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/2szjxzs0/6/

I'm sure someone can explain much more eloquently how this works and why this needs to be done, but at the very least it should solve your immediate problem.

Comment: Crazy that a call to `node.offsetHeight` fixes this, I also don't have any idea why this hack works in this case.

Comment: Thanks, nailed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-7-post-processing-or-animating-the-generated-dom-elements) of the `beforeRemove` event:

> `beforeRemove` — is invoked when an array item has been removed, but
>   before the corresponding DOM nodes have been removed. If you specify a
>   beforeRemove callback, **then it becomes your responsibility to remove
>   the DOM nodes.**

In your `beforeRemove` you only remove the DOM nodes if they are not text node but you need to remove all the nodes.

So you need to add an `else` case with `node.parentElement.removeChild(node);`:

```
me.animateOut = function animateOut(node, i, person) {
    // Make sure it's not a text node
    if (node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        node.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
            this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
        });
        node.classList.add("remove");
    }
    else{
        node.parentElement.removeChild(node);
    }
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qecwf0df/).

Comment: Thanks. It's probably best to remove the text nodes as well, but Explosion Pills nailed it with the redraw.

Comment: I think that the proper solution is remove the text nodes because in this case knockout properly handles the rendering and you don't hacks to force a redraw...

Comment: It does help, but the issue would still occur when removing an item while the last transition was still in progress. Forcing the redraw works.

Answer (score 1):

Your transition ends after the `remove` happens so it probably messes up the rendering.

You can fix this by notifying the `people` collection that the transition has ended.

```
me.animateOut = function animateOut(node, i, person) {
    // Make sure it's not a text node
    if (node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        node.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
            this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
            me.people.notifySubscribers(); // Add this line here
        });
        node.classList.add("remove");
    }
}
```

[Edited Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2szjxzs0/7/)

Note that if you have manual subscriptions they will be notified with an `undefined` argument to the notification callback so you should be ready for that.