# AngularJS angular-translate button text missing

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-translate

I am using AngularJS with angular-translate (pascalprecht).
I am experiencing an issue, where translated text on a button element doesn't show up, until I scroll the button out of the current view and scroll back in or redraw the page in some other way (like toggling display: none). The translated text is in place though (checking through inspector - chrome dev tools).

This happens on Chrome, I couldn't replicate it on Firefox. Translations are loaded with staticFileLoader (local file). The translation on the element is added this way:

```
<button class="button large x-wide" type="submit">{{ "SUBMIT" | translate }}</button>
```

I tried swapping the button element with an anchor ('a') element, but the error persists.

Comment: can you try adding a translate-cloak directive to the button?

Comment: I did: <button data-translate-cloak class="button large x-wide" type="submit">{{ "SUBMIT" | translate }}</button> but that didn't help. It doesn't even add the class upon load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched a bit more, and it seems this isn't related to AngularJS, but more to webkit [How can I force WebKit to redraw/repaint to propagate style changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes)

from the answers listed I tried a few. I didn't want to toggle display: none (that helps though). I tried adding a z-index, but it didn't help.

What did it, was adding an empty style tag after the button:

```
<button class="button large x-wide" type="submit">{{ "SUBMIT" | translate }}</button>
<style></style>
```

the translation shows up after a few seconds. This is not optimal, but works.