# ios8 UIWebview svg embaded html not show

Tags: html, ios, svg, uiwebview

I am recently working on a svg map app. everything is running fine on ios7. when i move my project to ios8. strange things happened, I found when UIWebview read local html file which has a svg file embedded, the svg file will not shown on ios8.

sample code is here:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[self.webView loadRequest:req];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

and the html file used:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>SVG DEMO</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <embed src="410.svg" width="64" height="64" type="image/svg+xml" />
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="410.svg" width="64" height="64" border="1"></object>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with my application.
And I found this solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Informations</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center><img src="logo.svg" width="200" height="200" /></center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Works with iOS 7.0.3 and 8.0

Comment: Although it works for static SVG, it doesn't help when SVG contains scripts.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that SVGs that had an animate tag showed up fine, while those without did not show up. Adding a dummy animate tag to the svg is the workaround I'm using for the time being.

```
...
<animate attributeName="opacity" values="0.99;1.0" dur="0.01s" begin="0s" repeatCount="1"></animate>
</svg>
```

**Update:**

This issue is fixed in iOS 8.1.2 (possibly earlier), so this is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using this solution [How can I force WebKit to redraw/repaint to propagate style changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes) solved it for me, without modifying the HTML structure through an image (I needed the svg to remain embeded).

So my final code is something of the like:

```
var emb = document.querySelector( '.myCSSClass');
svgItem = emb.getSVGDocument.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]

svgItem.style.display='none';
var somethinguseless = svgItem.offsetHeight; // SHOULD not need to store this anywhere, the reference is enough. Without a ref, the closure compiler removes it
svgItem.style.display='block';
```

Comment: I realise this is more a Javascript oriented solution which is the context in which I have the issue (web app)

Answer (score 0):

just FYI: I've tested iOS 8.1 Update this morning an SVGs in embed tags are fixed...