# Does getting the offsetHeight of an element have a side effect?

Tags: javascript, dom, side-effects, offsetheight

In the code for Bootstrap collapse, in the `hide()` method, I see the following line:

`this.$element[dimension](this.$element[dimension]())[0].offsetHeight`

I don't understand what the point of the `.offsetHeight` at the end is unless it has a side effect, because it's not being assigned to anything.  Does it have a side effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some old browsers like old versions of IE had the problem of sometimes not reflowing (re-rendering the presentation) after you performed some actions.

Mearly querying some properties like `offsetHeight` forces the DOM to recalculate and redraw the objects on the screen.

So, the side effect is forcing a reflow (redraw) of the screen. Quirky, but an old trick for old browsers.

Here is [a question where this is suggested as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3485365/1348195) for an old version of Google Chrome where it did not work properly without it.

Comment: In fact, some of the other instances have this noted in a comment: `if (doAnimate) this.$backdrop[0].offsetWidth // force reflow`

Comment: Not only "Some old browsers" but all of them. You cannot get valid offsetHeight without ensuring that rendering tree is up to date.

Answer (score 2):

here is a useful comment from [bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L205) team:

```
if (doAnimate) this.$backdrop[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
```