# Bullet colors don't display correctly in Chrome when changed by Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, google-chrome

Can anyone explain why these bullets will change color correctly in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome (my current version is 47.0.2526.106)? Why do the bullets in the first `ul` stay white, but the others change initially?

Note that I get the same behavior whether I bind to `class` or use the `ng-class` attribute.

Is there any way to get the colors to update correctly?

Firefox/IE:

[image: FFIE Example]

Chrome:

[image: Chrome Example]

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$interval',
    function($scope, $interval) {
      var values = ['Hello', 'Oops', 'Uh-Oh...'];
      var classes = ['good', 'warning', 'danger'];
      var nItems = 8;
      $scope.items = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < nItems; i++) {
        $scope.items.push({});
      }

      function updateItems() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
          var item = $scope.items[i];
          var chosen = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length);
          item.value = values[chosen];
          item.class = classes[chosen];
        }
      }

      $interval(updateItems, 3000);
    }
  ]);
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
.good {
  color: limegreen;
}
.warning {
  color: yellow;
}
.danger {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li class="{{item.class}}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li class="{{item.class}}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li ng-class="{'good': item.class==='good', 'warning': item.class==='warning', 'danger': item.class==='danger'}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

## Update

Coming back to this about a year later it appears Google has fixed the rendering bug that caused this, although I'm not sure exactly which release included the fix. I no longer see this issue on Chrome v56.0.2924.87.

Comment: Triggering a repaint event seems to resolve the issue for me in Chrome... although that is a hack-ish solution. I'm not aware of any other workarounds since this is definitely a rendering issue.

Comment: Clearly the root cause is the $interval statement.  Calling it with $timeout and at the end of the updateItems calling it again with another $timeout produces the same interval effect, but get the correct display.  Not sure why.  I'd love to hear the technicals behind this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Chrome rendering bug.

One option is to insert custom bullet points using a pseudo element.

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li:before {
  content: '\2022';
  text-indent: -1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the updated example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$interval',
    function($scope, $interval) {
      var values = ['Hello', 'Oops', 'Uh-Oh...'];
      var classes = ['good', 'warning', 'danger'];
      var nItems = 8;
      $scope.items = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < nItems; i++) {
        $scope.items.push({});
      }

      function updateItems() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
          var item = $scope.items[i];
          var chosen = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length);
          item.value = values[chosen];
          item.class = classes[chosen];
        }
      }

      $scope.getItemValue = function(item) {
        return item.value;
      };

      $interval(updateItems, 3000);
    }
  ]);
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li:before {
  content: '\2022';
  text-indent: -1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
.good {
  color: limegreen;
}
.warning {
  color: yellow;
}
.danger {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li class="{{item.class}}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li class="{{item.class}}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li ng-class="{'good': item.class==='good', 'warning': item.class==='warning', 'danger': item.class==='danger'}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Another option is to trigger a [repaint event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes) in order to force the browser to update the styling. This is definitely a hackish option, but nonetheless, it works:

```
function forceRepaint() {
  document.body.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.offsetHeight;
  document.body.style.display = '';
}
```

Here is the other updated example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$interval',
    function($scope, $interval) {
      var values = ['Hello', 'Oops', 'Uh-Oh...'];
      var classes = ['good', 'warning', 'danger'];
      var nItems = 8;
      $scope.items = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < nItems; i++) {
        $scope.items.push({});
      }

      function updateItems() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
          var item = $scope.items[i];
          var chosen = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length);
          item.value = values[chosen];
          item.class = classes[chosen];

          forceRepaint();
        }
      }

      $scope.getItemValue = function(item) {
        return item.value;
      };

      $interval(updateItems, 3000);
    }
  ]);


function forceRepaint() {
  document.body.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.offsetHeight;
  document.body.style.display = '';
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
.good {
  color: limegreen;
}
.warning {
  color: yellow;
}
.danger {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li class="{{item.class}}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li class="{{item.class}}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li ng-class="{'good': item.class==='good', 'warning': item.class==='warning', 'danger': item.class==='danger'}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a great workaround. Any idea *why* this occurs?

Answer (score 3):

A
s a commenter said this seems to be rendering bug, but here's a work around by just using `:before` to color the dots yourself. See the css section (just wanted to keep it runnable)

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$interval',
    function($scope, $interval) {
      var values = ['Hello', 'Oops', 'Uh-Oh...'];
      var classes = ['good', 'warning', 'danger'];
      var nItems = 8;
      $scope.items = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < nItems; i++) {
        $scope.items.push({});
      }

      function updateItems() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
          var item = $scope.items[i];
          var chosen = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length);
          item.value = values[chosen];
          item.class = classes[chosen];
        }
      }

      $scope.getItemValue = function(item) {
        return item.value;
      };

      $interval(updateItems, 3000);
    }
  ]);
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}
.good {
  color: limegreen;
}
.warning {
  color: yellow;
}
.danger {
  color: red;
}

/* made the dots yourself */
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

li { 
  padding-left: 1em; 
  text-indent: -.7em;
}

li.warning:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: yellow;
}

li.danger:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: red;
}

li.good:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li class="{{item.class}}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li class="{{item.class}}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li ng-class="{'good': item.class==='good', 'warning': item.class==='warning', 'danger': item.class==='danger'}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.value}}</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```