# Changing the bullet point color in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

It's easy to set a bullet point colour, but *changing* it doesn't seem to work in the latest version of Chrome (it works fine in Safari and Firefox).

For example *hover* the mouse over the elements in the code snippet:

```css
    li {
      list-style-type: disc;
      list-style-position: outside;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
    
    ul {
      transition: color .3s linear;
      color: red;
    }
    
    ul:hover {
      color: black;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWalkerDesign/uahnbovu/) (if you prefer that)

Comment: This is a Chrome rendering bug... to work around this, you could always use custom bullets like in the solutions to this question: [Bullet colors don't display correctly in Chrome when changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501539/bullet-colors-dont-display-correctly-in-chrome-when-changed-by-angular).

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thanks. I'd love to see the issue and track it to see when it's changed. It's a pain to have to change code for one browser's bugs... especially when it's Chrome and not IE for a change!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may remove all list styling and add a pseudo element which will make `<li>` elements look like having a disc style.

```
li {
    list-style: none;
}

li:before {
    content: '\25CF\00a0\00a0';
    display: inline;
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/uahnbovu/1/).

Comment: Sort of irrelevant to the OP, but related to your answer, is there such workarounds for ordered list as well? e.g. somehow including the increment and displaying in I., II., III., mainly ordered list styles?

Comment: @TheDeadLike You are probably looking for something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/uahnbovu/5/), but a pure CSS solution can only be done if the data attribute on each `<li>` is hard coded by a server-side script. (Sorry for the minimized JS btw, I already had the code :) )

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for the idea! My main idea was somehow combining with [this](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#counter-increment), but seems like the current item is only viable for ::marker select, only.