# How to hack around linear-gradient() with currentColor bug in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, colors, hover, linear-gradients

There's a bug in the latest Chrome release (49) where CSS like…

```
background: linear-gradient(currentColor, green);
```

…isn't updated when the `color` of the element changes (e.g. on :hover).

How do I hack around this?

Answer (score 7):

The rendering will update if the element is redrawn ([See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes)).

e.g.

You can force a redraw when the `color` of the element changes by additionally changing an arbitrary property that triggers a redraw.

The property should be…

1. webkit only (to reduce side-effects)
2. overridable (element will only be redrawn if value changes)
3. rarely important (because we need to assume that the property isn't set on the element yet to override it with the least consequences)
4. have no visible effects by itself

```css
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    
    background: linear-gradient(currentColor, green);
    
    color: #f00;
}

.box:hover {
    color: blue;
    
    /* arbitrary webkit-only property that forces a redraw */
    -webkit-margin-start: .1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border` to draw a block of color because border-color auto inherits the `color` prop, then draw a `linear-gradient(to right, white, transparent)` on it. Then the border block will look like a linear-gradient from white to the `currentColor`

See demo: the `.g2` shows the bug and `.gradient` shows the hack.

http://jsbin.com/luzute/1/edit?html,css,output

You can adjust the `white`'s transparency(like `rgba(255,255,255,0.5)`) to adjust the lighten of the gradient or change white to transparency black(`rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`) to deepen the gradient.

Comment: That's a valid option for this example. In some cases, you might still need to actually change the gradient's colors, though. For example if you want [multi-colored gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Gradient_with_multiple_color_stops) or if you need one of the gradient colors to be transparent while having an unpredictable background (like an image).