# CSS :hover rerender after covering element height 0

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, hover, rerender

I have an element which I call **`back`** covered by another element which I call **`front`**.

**`Back`** is set in CSS to change color on hover. **`Front`** is set, when hovered, to disappear after a **`1s`** delay and the mouse pointer which was on **`Front`** element now is on **back element**.

**`Front`** disappears by setting **`height: 0`** in JavaScript. After **`Front`** disappears and the mouse ointer is hovering on **`Back`** the browser doesn't rerender the hover effect on **`Back`** which results in its color not being changed as it should.

When I try the same example by naturally removing **`Front`** from the DOM it works fine. My app, though, requires I do this by setting **`height: 0`**.

You can try it for yourselves in the following examples. You will see a red box and a blue box. Red is **`Front`** and blue is **`Back`**. When you move the mouse pointer to the red box, the red box's color changes to **`green`**. When you move your mouse onto the blue box, after one second, it will disappear.

The point of the example is to show that after the blue box disappears, the mouse pointer now hovers on the red box and it should therefore become **`green`**.

In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/zkhorh38/1/), the blue box is removed from the DOM completely and it works as well as expected.

In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/zkhorh38/2/), though, the blue box is to be removed by setting **`height: 0`**. After disappearing, the red element won't become **`green`** until after I move the mouse.

Is there any way to force browser to rerender?

The problem persists in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge. Firefox works good.

Answer (score 6):

**Instead of trying to force the browser to rerender**, you can just add a class to **`foo`** that will make it green when **`bar`** disappears and then, it returns to normal on **`mouseleave`**.

**CSS**:

```css
#foo.hover, /* <- I just added this */
#foo:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var
  foo = document.getElementById("foo"),
  bar = document.getElementById("bar");

/* Set the 'mouseenter' event for bar to set the height to 0 and & the 'hover' class. */
bar.onmouseenter = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    bar.style.height = 0;
    foo.classList.add("hover");
  }, 1000);
}

/* Set the 'mouseleave' event for bar to remove the 'hover' class. */
bar.onmouseleave = function() {
  foo.classList.remove("hover");
}
```

Check out the following snippet for a visual representation.

**Snippet:**

```js
/* --- JavaScript --- */
var
  foo = document.getElementById("foo"),
  bar = document.getElementById("bar");

/* Set the 'mouseenter' event for bar. */
bar.onmouseenter = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    /* Set the height to 0. */
    bar.style.height = 0;
    
    /* Add the 'hover' class. */
    foo.classList.add("hover");
  }, 1000);
}

/* Set the 'mouseleave' event for bar. */
bar.onmouseleave = function() {
  /* Remove the 'hover' class. */
  foo.classList.remove("hover");
}
```

```css
/* --- CSS --- */
#foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 15px;
}
#foo.hover,
#foo:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
#bar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div id = "foo"></div>
<div id = "bar"></div>
```

Comment: I am looking for some without JS.

Answer (score 4):

This really seems like a browser issue, [there are some ways on how to force webkit to redraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes). But I really wouldn't recommend that for you. You can simply use `bar.style.display = 'none';` instead of setting the height to zero. Has the same effect and everything works as expected. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zkhorh38/4/.

Comment: My app uses nested elements (with `position: absolute`) in `front` (blue) element. Which `display: none` makes hidden but `height: 0` makes it visible.

Comment: Your solution works in Chrome but not in Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to do it in CSS just by playing with the **`transition`** property.

```css
#foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:red;
  position: absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:15px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#foo:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

#bar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:blue;
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  z-index: 20;
  
  transition: all 1000000s; 
}

#bar:hover {
  transition: all 0.01s;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a browser issue, but there are some ways on how to force webkit to redraw. But I wouldn't recommend that for you. You can simply use **`bar.style.display = 'none';`** instead of setting the height to zero.

**Another solution to force a redraw/repaint that works just fine:**

```
sel.style.display='none';
sel.offsetHeight; // no need to store this anywhere, the reference is enough
sel.style.display='';
```

**

To avoid flickering you may try `'inline-block'`, `'table'` or `'run-in'` instead of **`'none'`**, but this may have side-effects. Also, a timeout of 0 triggers a reflow just like querying offsetHeight does: **`sel.style.display = 'run-in'; setTimeout(function () { sel.style.display = 'block'; }, 0);`**

Try this it really works !

Comment: This really works and it is the best solution which have been posted here. But this does not work in Edge.

Comment: A common design pattern is to use a style class to toggle the style and content of an inline element such as anchors. jquery.mobile includes style classes to turn your anchor elements into toggle switches.

Answer (score 1):

If **back** is *completely* covered by **front**, you could set **`front.style['pointer-events'] = 'none'`** in the **`onmouseenter`** callback first to let the mouse activate **back**'s **`:hover`** rule before **front** disappears.

See [modified working snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/zkhorh38/15/).

Comment: It is not ma case but I consider using it in my project. It could me help.

Comment: Thanks you. pointerEvents property helps me in my case. Bounties are your but I think it is not answer to this general question.