# What css-attributes forces a reflow?

Tags: css

I'm using a transform scale to resize an image to a size larger than the browser-window. It's a zoom feature for mobile browsers.

```
transform: 'scale(3)'
```

The idea is that you should be able to pan around in the image on a mobile phone. But in Chrome the width of the document is not updated. I believe this is because the scale does not trigger a redrawing. If I apply for example position: absolute; the page will get redrawn.

What is a css-attribute that causes a redraw but does not generally have any effects on the styling?

Comment: Did you saw [this](https://csstriggers.com) site? There you find the different css triggers

Comment: Yes, but i'm kind of looking for a suggestion/idea for a good styling option.

Comment: Please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes

Comment: @luriidrozdov, I was that but none of those are css-sloutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using viewport width and height.

```
.img{
    width:300vw;
    height:300vh;
}
```