# Safari JS innerHTML bug/error

Tags: javascript, html, safari, innerhtml

I have a strange problem in a very simple form validation script. Using Chrome and Firefox there is no problem, but using safari the innerHTML of my `<p>` doesn't change correctly. The second problem is that I can't show it in a snippet because Snippets are too small. If a user first types an @ then a number and removes the number again, i got a mixed error message. (error message 3 and the second line of message 6). If I simply rescale the safari window by hand, the second line disappears. The same happens with the combination of a / and a number or a . and a number. Like you can see in the code.

Preview of the website: [Preview](http://www.north-wind.be/sites/templates/onepage-3/#forms)

To produce the error/bug i did this problem in third img in the green box:
Fill in an @
[image: Step 1]
Add a number 
[image: Step 2]
Remove the Number
[image: Step 3]

This is my HTML:

```
<h3 id="forms">Forms</h3>
<div class="forms">
    <form>
        <div class="input"><input placeholder="name" name="name" type="text" oninput="checkname(this.id)" id="name"><div><p id="namereaction" class="reaction"></p></div></div>
        <div class="input"><input placeholder="firstname" name="name" type="text" oninput="checkname(this.id)" id="firstname"><div><p id="firstnamereaction" class="reaction"></p></div></div>
        <div class="input"><input placeholder="mail" name="mail" type="email" oninput="checkmail()" id="mail"><div><p id="mailreaction" class="reaction"></p></div></div>
        <div class="input"><textarea name="text" id="textarea"></textarea><div id="textreactionbox"><p id="textareareaction" class="reaction"></p></div></div>
        <div class="input"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And my JS:

```
function checkname(id){
    var error="";
    var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
    if(value.length<1){
        error = "Please fill in your (first)name.";
    }
    if(value.length>50){
        error = "Please fill in your (first)name. Your name is to long.";
    }
    if (value.indexOf("@") > -1 ) {
        error = "I think you are filling in your emailadress";
    }
    if (value.indexOf(".") > -1 ) {
        error = "Please check your (first)name, most names don't have a '.'.";
    }
    if (value.indexOf("/") > -1 ) {
        error = "Please check your (first)name, most names don't have a '/'.";
    }
    var matches = value.match(/\d+/g);
    if (matches != null) {
        error = "Please check your (first)name, we are all people, our (first)name doesn't contain a number.";
    }
    if(error.length>1){
        document.getElementById(id+"reaction").innerHTML=error;
    }else{
        document.getElementById(id+"reaction").innerHTML="";
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a Snippet it works on my mac, but in a normal website it doesn't work. I have the latest version on my Macbook Pro.

Comment: But how can we help you without the snippet with the problem?

Comment: If it doesn't work in a normal website but work in a snippet (I've actually tried this on a normal website with all the code you've supplied and it works well), then it must mean that you have not supplied all your code to us.

Comment: It works in a normal website

Comment: Ok, I will add a preview of the site : [link](http://www.north-wind.be/sites/templates/onepage-3/). On my computer I still get the same problem like i have explained in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a Safari's render bug because I can reproduce it only in Safari with:

1. The specific custom font ([Aqua](http://fontm.com/aqua/), on other custom font it isn't reproducible);
2. The specific block size (when there are 2 lines of text).

Chrome and Firefox don't really load the font because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) problems:

[image: CORS]

But Safari does, you can check it out on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/maLtr64k/3/).

*This snippet below only for history because that particular font on your site available only by HTTP (but SO snippets need HTTPS):*

```js
function checkname(id) {
  var error = "";
  var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
  if (value.length < 1) {
    error = "Please fill in your (first)name.";
  }
  if (value.length > 50) {
    error = "Please fill in your (first)name. Your name is to long.";
  }
  if (value.indexOf("@") > -1) {
    error = "I think you are filling in your emailadress";
  }
  if (value.indexOf(".") > -1) {
    error = "Please check your (first)name, most names don't have a '.'.";
  }
  if (value.indexOf("/") > -1) {
    error = "Please check your (first)name, most names don't have a '/'.";
  }
  var matches = value.match(/\d+/g);
  if (matches != null) {
    error = "Please check your (first)name, we are all people, our (first)name doesn't contain a number.";
  }
  if (error.length > 1) {
    document.getElementById(id + "reaction").innerHTML = error;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id + "reaction").innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Aqua";
  src: url(http://north-wind.be/css/aqua.ttf) format("truetype");
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 24px auto;
  font-family: Aqua, Arial;
}

.input input[type=text],
.input input[type=email] {
  border: 1pt solid limegreen;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.input div {
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
  width: 350px;
  background: limegreen;
  color: white;
  height: 36px;
  float: left;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.input div p {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="forms">Forms</h3>
<div class="forms">
  <form>
    <div class="input">
      <input placeholder="name" name="name" type="text" oninput="checkname(this.id)" id="name">
      <div>
        <p id="namereaction" class="reaction"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

So, I can only suggest you to use [one of force redraw/repaint hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes), for example:

```
var element = document.getElementById(id + 'reaction');
if (error.length > 1) {
  element.innerHTML = error;
} else {
  element.innerHTML = '';
}
element.style.display = 'none';
element.offsetHeight;
element.style.display = '';
```

[The fixed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/maLtr64k/7/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is still not working for me.

Comment: @North-Wind it's not working for you in my snippet or on your site?

Comment: After a google about safari render bug i have found a solution similar to your answer. The snippet works, but the code like shown above doesn't work on my webpage.

Comment: @North-Wind which solution did suit you?

Comment: I will post it soon!

Comment: @North-Wind have you tried to add `transform: translateZ(0)` to `.input div p {...}`?

Comment: He's for you ;)